# Problema con ejercicio de Java en NetBeans

Tags: java

Estoy estudiando 1º de DAW y me encuentro un atascada en este ejercicio de Java, por más vueltas que le doy no soy capaz de resolverlo.
Quizás esté interpretando mal el enunciado, no sé...

Diseña un programa Java que cree un tipo enumerado para los meses del año. El programa debe realizar las siguientes operaciones:

- Crear una variable m del tipo enumerado y asignarle el mes de marzo. Mostrar por pantalla su valor.
- Asignar a la variable m, la cadena de texto "MARZO". Mostrar por pantalla el valor de la variable de tipo enumerado tras realizar la asignación.

Aquí es donde me he quedado, espero vuestras respuestas.
Un saludo!!

```
public class meses_anio {

enum meses{Enero, Febrero, Marzo, Abril, Mayo, Junio, Julio, Agosto, Septiembre, Octubre, Noviembre, Diciembre};
public static void main(String[] args) {

    meses m=meses.Marzo;

    System.out.println("Mes de: " + m);
```

Comment: El enunciado tal cual está escrito no tiene sentido: si la variable `m` es de tipo meses, no puedes asignarle un `String`. Por otro lado te recomiendo que uses las [convenciones de Java](https://javadesdecero.es/fundamentos/convenciones-nomenclatura-java/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

si se le puede asignar un string a un enum, te dejo ejemplo

```
public class Test {
    public static <T> void main(String[] args)  {


        String mes = "MARZO";   
        Meses m = Meses.MARZO;
        System.out.println("--> "+m );
        m = Meses.valueOf(mes);
        System.out.println("--> "+m);
    }
}
```

salida por pantalla

--> 1 MARZO
--> 2 MARZO

Existen algunos otros métodos para convertir String a Enum que compara String pasado con todas las instancias de Enum declaradas iterando sobre todas las instancias de Enum usando el método de valores () y luego comparándolas usando equals (). Aunque ese método funciona bien, requiere más código que el simple Enum.valueOf ().

te dejo el mi clase enum

```
package patofer;

public enum Meses {

   ENERO("ENERO"),
   FEBRERO("FEBRERO"),
   MARZO("MARZO"),
   ABRIL("ABRIL"),
   MAYO("MAYO"),
   JUNIO("JUNIO"),
   JULIO("JULIO"),
   AGOSTO("AGOSTO"),
   SEPTIEMBRE("SEPTIEMBRE"),
   OCTUBRE("OCTUBRE"),
   NOVIEMBRE("NOVIEMBRE"),
   DICIEMBRE("DICIEMBRE");

   private final String codigo;

   private Meses(String code) {
       this.codigo = code;
   }

   public String getCode() {
       return codigo;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo veo que esta bien, entiendo algo asi

```
public class NewMain {
enum meses {Enero, Febrero, Marzo, Abril, Mayo, Junio, Julio, Agosto, Septiembre, Octubre, Noviembre, Diciembre};
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String m = meses.Marzo.toString();
        System.out.println("Mes de: " + m);
        m = "MARZO";
        System.out.println("el mes es " + m);
    }
}
```

salida:

```
run:
Mes de: Marzo
el mes es MARZO
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Esta respuesta tiene 2 problemas

1.- m no es de tipo enum
2.- es un String, por ende podrías poner cualquier cosa y el sistema no lo reconocería como error.

la idea de trabajar con Enum son valores fijos oseas contantes, no se puedes ingresar cualquier valor.